# simpleXML loop entries

Tags: php, simplexml

i have the xml below

```
    <entry>
        <id></id>
        <title></title>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:relation></dc:relation>
        <dc:publisher></dc:publisher>
        <dc:language xsi:type="dcterms:ISO639-2"></dc:language>
        <dcterms:issued></dcterms:issued>
        <updated></updated>
        <rights></rights>
        <author>
            <name></name>
            <uri></uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="alternate" href="" type="text/html"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/image" href="" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/image/thumbnail" href="" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/acquisition/buy" href="" type="application/epub+zip">
            <opds:price currencycode="EUR"></opds:price>
        </link>
        <summary type="text"></summary>
</entry>
<entry>
        <id></id>
        <title></title>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:relation></dc:relation>
        <dc:publisher></dc:publisher>
        <dc:language xsi:type="dcterms:ISO639-2"></dc:language>
        <dcterms:issued></dcterms:issued>
        <updated></updated>
        <rights></rights>
        <author>
            <name></name>
            <uri></uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="alternate" href="" type="text/html"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/image" href="" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/image/thumbnail" href="" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <link rel="http://opds-spec.org/acquisition/buy" href="" type="application/epub+zip">
            <opds:price currencycode="EUR"></opds:price>
        </link>
        <summary type="text"></summary>
</entry>
......
```

I can parse it fine when parsing all items (simpleXML)

Now i want to get one item at the time.So i passing a var to my file like

```
file.php?start=1
file.php?start=2
etc
```

and i tried to access the current item

```
$xml->entry[$start] returns NULL
```

OR

```
 $xml->entry->{$start} returns NULL
```

but both returns NULL

I tried to access it directly

```
$xml->entry[1]
$xml->entry->{1}
```

and its working fine

Am i missing somehthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET['start'] is perhaps not proper variable type, try type casting to integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('simplexml.php');

$id = '1';
print_r($xml->entry[$id]);
?>
```

**Result:**

NULL

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('simplexml.php');

$id = '1';
$id = (int)$id;

print_r($xml->entry[$id]);

?>
```

**Result:**

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [entry] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => The Other Title
        )
)